# JMeter does not replace ${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1} with its value

Tags: jmeter

It's a long story, but I will try make it simple:

1. I generated [MeterMaid](http://github.com/sugarcrm/MeterMaid) XML files with [SugarMMM](http://github.com/sugarcrm/SugarMMM); I chose only the Accounts module:

   [image]
2. I converted above files to JMeter format with MeterMaid (I consolidated the tests into one file and named it "filename.xml"):

   ```
    ruby GenMeter.rb --inputfile=filename.xml --outputfile=filename.jmx
   ```
3. I did the necessary CSV setup. All the CSV file contains is the login details (`usr,pwd`) for testing concurrent user logins. This part works well indeed.

When I run the test, I can see that a whole bunch of `${}` variables are converted into corresponding values. Sadly, `${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1}` doesn't get resolved... here's what the GET url (from **View Results Tree** Listener component) looks like:

```
http://localhost/sugarcrm/index.php?module=${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1}&action=Popup&hide_clear_button=true&mode=MultiSelect&create=true&metadata=undefined
```

Note that it's not the only variable that isn't resolved. The following screenshot shows the other tests that fail, all also caused by other variables not replaced by their corresponding values:

[image]

Here's how this variable is set up (which is well before the time it's used):

[image]

Here's what **[Debug Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)** says:

```
JMeterVariables:
CAMPAIGN_ID=CAMPAIGN_ID_ERROR
CAMPAIGN_NAME=CAMPAIGN_NAME_ERROR
CONTACT_ID=997a3171-aa60-b2d6-a457-4e0ba8b0052b
CONTACT_ID_g=4
CONTACT_ID_g0=onclick="send_back('Contacts','997a3171-aa60-b2d6-a457-4e0ba8b0052b');">Prof
CONTACT_ID_g1=onclick="send_back('Contacts','
CONTACT_ID_g2=997a3171-aa60-b2d6-a457-4e0ba8b0052b
CONTACT_ID_g3=');">
CONTACT_ID_g4=Prof
CONTACT_NAME=Prof
CONTACT_NAME_g=4
CONTACT_NAME_g0=onclick="send_back('Contacts','997a3171-aa60-b2d6-a457-4e0ba8b0052b');">Prof
CONTACT_NAME_g1=onclick="send_back('Contacts','
CONTACT_NAME_g2=997a3171-aa60-b2d6-a457-4e0ba8b0052b
CONTACT_NAME_g3=');">
CONTACT_NAME_g4=Prof
FOUND_ID=1
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@3c1635
MEMBER_OF_ID=d7c26344-cad8-0503-b02a-4e0cb4db3985
MEMBER_OF_ID_g=4
MEMBER_OF_ID_g0=onclick="send_back('Accounts','d7c26344-cad8-0503-b02a-4e0cb4db3985');">searchSearchForm
MEMBER_OF_ID_g1=onclick="send_back('Accounts','
MEMBER_OF_ID_g2=d7c26344-cad8-0503-b02a-4e0cb4db3985
MEMBER_OF_ID_g3=');">
MEMBER_OF_ID_g4=searchSearchForm
MEMBER_OF_NAME=searchSearchForm
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g=4
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g0=onclick="send_back('Accounts','d7c26344-cad8-0503-b02a-4e0cb4db3985');">searchSearchForm
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g1=onclick="send_back('Accounts','
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g2=d7c26344-cad8-0503-b02a-4e0cb4db3985
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g3=');">
MEMBER_OF_NAME_g4=searchSearchForm
OPPORTUNITY_ID=864e402f-0d76-ab6e-b54f-4e0cb42f0249
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g=4
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g0=onclick="send_back('Opportunities','864e402f-0d76-ab6e-b54f-4e0cb42f0249');">value
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g1=onclick="send_back('Opportunities','
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g2=864e402f-0d76-ab6e-b54f-4e0cb42f0249
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g3=');">
OPPORTUNITY_ID_g4=value
OPPORTUNITY_NAME=value
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g=4
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g0=onclick="send_back('Opportunities','864e402f-0d76-ab6e-b54f-4e0cb42f0249');">value
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g1=onclick="send_back('Opportunities','
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g2=864e402f-0d76-ab6e-b54f-4e0cb42f0249
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g3=');">
OPPORTUNITY_NAME_g4=value
RANDOM_CHAR=o
RANDOM_CHAR_g=1
RANDOM_CHAR_g0=o
RANDOM_CHAR_g1=o
RANDOM_STRING=value
RANDOM_STRING_g=1
RANDOM_STRING_g0=value
RANDOM_STRING_g1=value
RECORD_NAME=NOT_FOUND
RECORD_NUMBER=3250317d-6c79-b20d-5e36-4e0cb4746e84
RECORD_NUMBER_g=2
RECORD_NUMBER_g0=javascript:lvg_nav('Accounts', '3250317d-6c79-b20d-5e36-4e0cb4746e84
RECORD_NUMBER_g1=javascript:lvg_nav('Accounts', '
RECORD_NUMBER_g2=3250317d-6c79-b20d-5e36-4e0cb4746e84
SEARCH_FIELD=SEARCH_FIELD_ERROR
START.HMS=190308
START.MS=1309453388621
START.YMD=20110630
SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE=Accounts
TEAM_ID=seed-Teams8
TEAM_ID_g=4
TEAM_ID_g0=onclick="send_team_to_form('Teams','seed-Teams8');">Ball
TEAM_ID_g1=onclick="send_team_to_form('Teams','
TEAM_ID_g2=seed-Teams8
TEAM_ID_g3=');">
TEAM_ID_g4=Ball
TEAM_NAME=Ball
TEAM_NAME_g=4
TEAM_NAME_g0=onclick="send_team_to_form('Teams','seed-Teams8');">Ball
TEAM_NAME_g1=onclick="send_team_to_form('Teams','
TEAM_NAME_g2=seed-Teams8
TEAM_NAME_g3=');">
TEAM_NAME_g4=Ball
TESTSTART.MS=1309455500088
pwd=user1
usr=user1
```

**UPDATE**:

Here's after changing **Template** to `$1$$2$$3$$4$`:

[image]

And here's the Debug output (the Sampler is put just after regex Controller):

```
JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@18fde89
RANDOM_CHAR=t
RANDOM_CHAR_g=1
RANDOM_CHAR_g0=t
RANDOM_CHAR_g1=t
RANDOM_STRING=Tanzania
RANDOM_STRING_g=1
RANDOM_STRING_g0=Tanzania
RANDOM_STRING_g1=Tanzania
RECORD_NAME=NOT_FOUND
RECORD_NUMBER=DOCTYPE
RECORD_NUMBER_g=1
RECORD_NUMBER_g0=DOCTYPE
RECORD_NUMBER_g1=DOCTYPE
START.HMS=100932
START.MS=1312531772599
START.YMD=20110805
SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE=Accounts
TESTSTART.MS=1312542237235
pwd=user1
usr=user1
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify in your CSV dataset config, all variables are declared correctly (no typos, no omissions, no spaces before variable names, etc.)

I would also suggest putting a [debug sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) high in your tree, as it will show you every variable and its value and can save a lot of time.

**Edit:**

It looks like your regex is setup incorrectly for creating multiple groups.  If you look in your Debug sampler, you have `SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE=Accounts`  but not `SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1=` . This implies you don't have GROUPS setup.

In looking at your regex, the line `template: $0$`  is saying "only give me one group", whereas it looks like you want 4.  Thus, you should try `template: $1$$2$$3$$4$`  the first match should be `_g1` the second `_g2` and so on.  Check out the [manual for details.](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem after changing the template.

Comment: Do you have match no. set to -1 ? (Negative One)

Comment: Are you saying that's what I must use? If I do, I get the same problem.

Comment: Ah sorry - lost track of what you were trying to achieve. -1 is to receive all matches to use with a ForEach controller.  Can you post an updated regex and debug output to see what you've changed?  In the current regex controller, it looks like your variable name has spaces instead of underscores.

Comment: I wonder how that underscore thing happened. Maybe a problem with the screenshot instead of with the actual data. I have updated the question... please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

make judicious use of the ${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1} variable throughout the script after it gets defined by the Regular Expression Extractor.  Verify it exists. Use it in Controller titles, test headings, at the beginning of tests, and at the end of tests.

That will help narrow it down

This way you can follow it along in the script to make sure it exists just before the moment it is used, and find where it's breaking down.  Basically print statement debugging.

Comment: How do I put it in Controller titles or the rest of the other places?

Comment: add the variable to the Name section of a controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sugar CRM or metermaid but for jmeter I had a similar problem with variable that were not resolve.

Check if this variable is declared somewhere or maybe you need to write a reg ex to extract that value from the previous request.

The problem I got It was that I extracted the variable from a CSV files

the variable name was **CONTRACTNO, CLIENTNO**

my URL : */SomeURL/bla?eventId=contractSelected&contractNoSelected=${CONTRACTNO}&applicationID=BLa*

And it wasn't working so I changed the variable name in the csv file to :

**CONTRACTNO,CLIENTNO** (look that I removed a space)

Jmeter tend to be very picky with space in name and variable definition.

Comment: The only variables I put in the CSV file are the username and password and they work okay (I get multiple user logins). Other variables are found in the regex elements, including SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE.

Comment: from what I see it's that the variable in the URL is its seem to get on the default SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE, try running your reg ex in jakarta oro (that the one jmeter use) http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html there probably something wrong with your parsing since your not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the following values

```
${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1}
```

but you have configured the Regular Expression Extractor reference name as

```
"SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE"
```

There two options you can get the values

1. You have to change the `${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE_g1}` into `${SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE}`
2. You have to change the Regular Expression Extractor reference name as `"SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE _g1"` to `"SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE"`

After this your values will be replaced properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regular expression isn't picking up a match, your default value is set to "Accounts" and in your debug output that's the value of the variable. You'll only get match groups if the regular expression matches.

The View Results Tree listener now has a RegExp tester, so you can go to the request that you're trying to extract the variable SUBPANEL_RELATE_MODULE from the result in the results tree and choose RegExp Tester from the dropdown where it says "Text".

You can then run your regular expression on the response data in the RegExp tester and probably find that it doesn't match and then hone your regular expression so that it matches and update it in your Regular Expression Extractor.